# Carport steps too long

Tags: stairs

The steps in the picture below are too long lengthwise for me to be able to park full sized pickup truck very easily. The steps touch the corner of the truck when parked under there. I was wondering if I could cut the steps from left side(so open cut end would be against wall) to shorten the length across of steps without sacrificing its ability to support weight as it did before. I wouldn’t need to cut off much if I did, for it probably would be less than a foot cut off.  Would angle grinder be best choice to do it with?[image][image]

Comment: No the entire precast structure is supported by the two side ends

Comment: I had a feeling that would be true. Is the material cement or concrete?

Comment: No, you can't make those stairs narrower. The IRC would not allow it.

Comment: If new steps are purchased, could I get 36 inch length steps or does it have to be 48 inch according to IRC.

Comment: You can’t have steps misaligned with door opening. Which way dies door swing?

Comment: It swings inward toward laundry room.

Comment: The answer by Lee covers most everything. Keeping in mind that the edge of right side has to be in line with opening yiu are really limited on how much space yiu can gain. If you backed in you could squeeze closer to other side of carport and your drivers side door would be opening on the step side

Comment: That’s true. Backing in would be difficult with limited vision directly behind vehicle (Older truck that doesn’t have backup cameras of any sort).

Answer (score 1):

The maximum riser height is 8”. So, if the dimension from floor to floor is 16” or less, then you only need one tread. (See IRC R311.7.5.1)

Treads can be a minimum of 9”. (See IRC R311.7.5.2) However, I’d caution you on using a 9” tread with a 8” rise. Very awkward and I think dangerous.

Stair width is 36” minimum. However, a little known clause allows a 30” wide tread if there are at least two stairways leading to the same space and one of the stairways is at least 36” wide. (See IRC R311.7.1, Exception #2.). (I presume you have a stair from the front door to your overhead garage door that would be acceptable.)

BTW, the code discusses “walk lines”. I would make sure the edge of the steps align with the doorway opening...not the door trim, but the edge of the door opening. In your picture, it looks like you could reduce the step 2” or so from current length.

Comment: Those steps are only one in carport, so I couldn’t use exception 2. I believe the problem with reducing it 2 inches is that precast steps like those wouldn’t come in such a size(45-46 inches I am guessing ). Thanks for your reply and explanation.

Comment: @georgia-guy Oh, I’m not thinking of reducing the length of your pre-cast steps. I’m thinking of replacing those steps. AND the second set of steps don’t have to be “in” the carport. There just needs to be another set somewhere on the premises. They don’t have to be handy. Just another way to get down...somehow. If it’s 16” from level to level, you could build one wood step.

Comment: There are two other sets of steps on property. A brick one with longer tread than those and another with shorter tread than one pictured. I know the door is 36 inches wide, so steps will have to be at least that wide. It is 20 inches high from floor of carport to floor of laundry room,so I will need to stay at 2 steps. Existing steps is 48 inches across. So I guess my options would be to purchase precast steps 36 inches wide or make some with same measurements and that are IRC compliant.

Comment: I humbly submit that the IRC code in the 2015 and 2012 editions and possibly earlier versions, require the tread to be no less than 10" (measured nose to nose horizontally) and have a nosing of no less than 3/4" and no more than 1 1/4". The exception is if the tread is 11" or more, the nose is not required. Rise has been limited to 7 3/4" max. In older BOCA and CABO versions, the code was 9" tread and 8" rise

Comment: @Jack I’m using the 2017. Effective October 1, 2017.